# Angular Js Issue with data-ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an angular Js program like below.

**HTML**

```
<input data-ng-model="test" type="radio" name="rdButton" id="userLbl" value="mine"/> Mine

<input data-ng-model="test" type="radio" name="rdButton" id="userLbl" value="Other"/> Other

<textarea data-ng-disabled="test==='mine'"  data-ng-model="htmlSpace" type="text"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("Mydirective",[]);

app.controller("MyController",function($scope){
    $scope.test = "mine";
});
```

The text area is getting disabled only when I select the radio button with value mine.I am expecting it to be disabled when the page loads only, cause I mentioned the value as mine in the controller. But its always enabled, Please help me with the issue

Comment: Its working fine I guess . check the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/YvkBJDQZRFy9xNKu0XTn?p=preview

Comment: Could be the your $scope.test variable is set on the wrong scope level. 
Ex: You use a ng-if or ng-repeat around this control. That creates a new child scope level.
One way to test is to display the value of test that the HTML file sees right there next to the text area using {{ test }}
Sometimes, creating a javascript object fixes this parent/child scope issue. So at the top of your controller create
$scope.dataHolder = { data: 'mine' }; and  then bind to "dataHolder.data".

Comment: just as a quick check to see if its seeing your controller set the variable outside your controller to `$rootScope.test = mine` see if that fixes it. if it does you know your controllers not reaching the html.

or put an alert in your controller to show its being hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, please check below sample and check your angular version as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example88-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="Mydirective">
  <script>
var app = angular.module("Mydirective",[]);

app.controller("MyController",function($scope){
    $scope.test = "mine";

});
</script>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<input data-ng-model="test" type="radio" name="rdButton" id="userLbl" value="mine"/> Mine

<input data-ng-model="test" type="radio" name="rdButton" id="userLbl" value="Other"/> Other

<textarea data-ng-disabled="test==='mine'"  data-ng-model="htmlSpace" type="text"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gBN41mrNfDXbEDLZchCp?p=preview